# Image isn't loading or appearing in element source

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to display an image on my site.

Here's my main.js:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize']);

    myApp.factory('Cards', function() {
        var Cards = {};
        Cards.sets = [
    {
     "name":"Theros",
       "code":"THS",
       "releaseDate":"2013-09-27",
       "border":"black",
       "type":"expansion",
       "block":"Theros",
       "cards":[
          {
             "layout":"normal",
             "type":"Creature -- Demon",
             "types":[
                "Creature"
             ],
             "colors":[
                "Black"
             ],
             "multiverseid":373661,
             "name":"Abhorrent Overlord",
             "subtypes":[
                "Demon"
             ],
             "cmc":7,
             "rarity":"Rare",
             "artist":"Slawomir Maniak",
             "power":"6",
             "toughness":"6",
             "manaCost":"{5}<img src=\"resources/images/manaSymbols/black.png\"><img src=\"resources/images/manaSymbols/black.png\">",
             "text":"Flying<br /><br />When Abhorrent Overlord enters the battlefield, put a number of 1/1 black Harpy creature tokens with flying onto the battlefield equal to your devotion to black. (Each <img src=\"resources/images/manaSymbols/black.png\"> in the mana costs of permanents you control counts toward your devotion to black.)<br /><br />At the beginning of your upkeep, sacrifice a creature.",
             "number":"75",
             "imageName":"abhorrent overlord"
          }
          ]

    }
        ];
        return Cards;
    })
```

And here's my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Magic Cards</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="foundation/css/foundation.min.css">
</head>
<body>

  <div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="CardsCtrl">
        <input type="text" ng-model="search.$">
        <table ng-repeat="set in cards.sets | orderBy:'releaseDate'">
            <tr>
                <td colspan=5><h3><b><i>{{set.name}} -- </i></b></h3><h5><b><i>{{set.block}}</i></b></h5></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td width=200><b>CARD NAME</b></td>
                <td width=300><b>CARD TYPE</b></td>
                <td width=200><b>MANA COST</b></td>
                <td width=200><b>COLORS</b></td>
                <td width=75><b>CMC</b></td>
                <td><b>TEXT</b></td>                
            </tr>

            <tr ng-repeat="cards in set.cards | orderBy:'name' | filter:search">
                <td enter>{{cards.name}}</td>
                <td>{{cards.type}}</td>
                <td ng-bind-html="cards.manaCost"></td>
                <td>{{cards.colors}}</td>
                <td>{{cards.cmc}}</td>
                <td ng-bind-html="cards.text"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>  
    </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.3/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.4/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to escape the quotation marks, as you can tell. But when I inspect the element(in Chrome), all I see is `<img>`. I can tell that this is going to be something completely stupid that I'm missing, but it's been bugging me. Any suggestions?

Comment: Seems to work in this plunker:  http://plnkr.co/edit/S4HzQ0nbYld0eBoF1l8o?p=preview

Comment: @KayakDave: Allow me to point out that you're using an absolute URL, where as I'm trying to do this with a relative path. You are correct, it works in your plunker, and if I change it to an absolute path, it works. But I'm trying to keep it relative.

Answer (score 0):

#### From [ngBindHtml docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angBindHtml)

> By default, the innerHTML-ed content will be sanitized using the **`$sanitize`** service

#### From [$sanitize docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize.%24sanitize)

> The input is sanitized by parsing the html into tokens. All safe tokens (from a whitelist) are then serialized back to properly escaped html string. This means that no unsafe input can make it into the returned string, however, since our parser is more strict than a typical browser parser, it's possible that some obscure input, which would be recognized as valid HTML by a browser, won't make it through the sanitizer. The whitelist is configured using the functions **`aHrefSanitizationWhitelist`** and **`imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist`** of **`$compileProvider`**.

#### From [$compileProvider docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24compileProvider)

> **imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist(regexp)**
>
> Retrieves or overrides the default regular expression that is used for whitelisting of safe urls during img[src] sanitization.
>   The sanitization is a security measure aimed at prevent XSS attacks via html links.
>   Any url about to be assigned to img[src] via data-binding is first normalized and turned into an absolute url. Afterwards, the url is matched against the imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist regular expression. If a match is found, the original url is written into the dom. Otherwise, the absolute url is prefixed with 'unsafe:' string and only then is it written into the DOM.

#### Finally, the original `imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist`:

```
var imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist = /^\s*(https?|ftp|file):|data:image\//;
```

- Your relative images (`<img src="/path/img.jpg">`) are not matched so they get "sanitized".
- @KayakDave plunker works because absolute urls  do match that `regex`.

#### solution:

```
app.config(function($compileProvider){
  var regex = // whatever you need to match
  $compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist(regex);
})
```